# C# & SQL Server : stuck at inserting 32,765 records in a Transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server

I seem to understand what is happening but I'm lost really. I have a transaction in Visual Studio, Winforms, C#

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Program.connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlTransaction processTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ...
        }

        processTransaction.Commit();
        processTransaction.Dispose();

        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        processTransaction.Rollback();
        processTransaction.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The problem is: I'm inserting and looping a dataset of 93'000 rows, more or less, but it is stopping at 32,765. I googled and researched and said that the limit of `int` is `2,147,483,647`. Then the limit for `int` in Turbo C is I think more or less `32767`. I have a Backgroundworker but it just displays how many loops I did

```
this.label1.Text = (int.Parse(this.label1.Text) + 1).ToString();
```

What seems to be the problem?

EDIT: The exception that I'm receiving is that the loop is completed. The same error as "zombie transaction".

> This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

Comment: have you got any exception? if yes please share it.

Comment: @Wowie thanks. does gotqn's answer solved your issue? i think he answered your question corrrectly.

Comment: Check where you use the variable _processTransaction_ after its initialization. It should be only at loop exit to commit or in the catch block to rollback

Comment: @Wowie can you please share the code inside your for loop ?

Answer (score 3):

The limit of [smallint](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is 32,767 so I guess you need to change the column type to greater one.

Comment: Hello, you can see in my for loop that im using `int`. and not `smallint` And where will i change? I trie changing the int in my loop to `long` but the `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()` doesnt recognize it.

Comment: @Wowie Where are you inserting the data?

Comment: in SQL Server 2017

Comment: I mean - you are inserting the data in the table right? So, could you check the table definition - columns names and types? I am guessing one of this column has type `smallint` and when you try to insert a bigger value an error is thrown.

Comment: im inserting names. Not the value of 93k, what i mean of the 93k is the rows im intended to insert. :)

Comment: Yes, but if your table has column `ID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)` for example, if you try to insert more then the allowed number of rows, an error is thrown. So, could you check the table definition?

Comment: If the problem is caused by an overflow then it happens exactly after 32765 rows? And why the error message talks about a transaction no more usable? I suggest to remove the try/catch so VS will stop exactly on the line that cause the problem.